# CSS3 Flexbox Correct way of using specific layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Image layout:

[image]

I am trying to make this flexible layout with flexbox and only came up with this. I have no idea how to make it possible without `position: absolute`.
Is it possible to do with

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.container > * {
    padding: 10px;
 flex: 1 100%;
 color: white;
}
.content {
    order: 1;
    background: green;
}
.ads {
    order: 2;
    background: blue;
}
.comments {
    order: 3;
    background: red;
}
@media all and (min-width: 940px) {

    .content, .comments{
  flex: 0  1 80%;
  margin-right: 10px;
 }
    .ads {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
        order: 2;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Flex</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
   <div class="content">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam enim nisl, accumsan quis nisi sed, tempor dapibus libero. Aliquam condimentum consectetur mauris, vel eleifend est venenatis sit amet. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin in felis at quam bibendum bibendum non sed tellus. Nulla efficitur tincidunt elementum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Suspendisse euismod justo dui, non mollis nisl vulputate ut. Suspendisse vehicula sagittis orci, eget accumsan tortor pretium non. Sed finibus facilisis tortor at elementum. Curabitur tincidunt molestie ipsum vel iaculis.

Etiam ornare elit nec arcu facilisis, vel tempus ante facilisis. Pellentesque non libero ante. Nullam justo arcu, sollicitudin id malesuada ac, ultricies ac dolor. Nulla nunc felis, dignissim vel iaculis id, ultrices nec sem. Nulla fringilla lacus vitae metus porta tincidunt a id sapien. Suspendisse mollis metus non dolor consequat pellentesque. Donec rutrum odio ac sapien efficitur, at efficitur nisl dictum. Maecenas vitae arcu eget enim viverra eleifend. Mauris at dolor placerat, varius ante quis, consequat elit. Sed sodales congue bibendum. Morbi convallis eros vel nulla sagittis eleifend vel in lacus. Etiam imperdiet lorem eu turpis rutrum venenatis.
   </div>
   <div class="comments">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
   </div>
   <div class="ads">
    <img src="http://demo.joomshaper.com/2012/neo/images/stories/demo/vertical-banner.jpg" />
   </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work

Comment: It works almost, but if "Ads" box height becomes longer, it will stretch "Content" box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use flexbox for this, you can just use floating techniques.

- Have your `.ads` container come after your main content in your markup, since this makes sense semantically (You want ads to follow your content on mobile devices)
- Have your main content float left and your ads float right on the big screens, giving each a percentage of the width to take up:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;    
}
.container{
  overflow: hidden; /* One way of clearing our floated elements */
}
.content{
    background-color: #349900;
}
.ads{
    background-color: #0166fe;
}
.comments{
    background-color: #fe0000;    
}

@media screen and (min-width: 940px){
    .content{
        float: left;
        width: 70%;
    }
    .ads{
        float: right;
        width: 30%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam enim nisl, accumsan quis nisi sed, tempor dapibus libero. Aliquam condimentum consectetur mauris, vel eleifend est venenatis sit amet. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin in felis at quam bibendum bibendum non sed tellus. Nulla efficitur tincidunt elementum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Suspendisse euismod justo dui, non mollis nisl vulputate ut. Suspendisse vehicula sagittis orci, eget accumsan tortor pretium non. Sed finibus facilisis tortor at elementum. Curabitur tincidunt molestie ipsum vel iaculis. Etiam ornare elit nec arcu facilisis, vel tempus ante facilisis. Pellentesque non libero ante. Nullam justo arcu, sollicitudin id malesuada ac, ultricies ac dolor. Nulla nunc felis, dignissim vel iaculis id, ultrices nec sem. Nulla fringilla lacus vitae metus porta tincidunt a id sapien. Suspendisse mollis metus non dolor consequat pellentesque. Donec rutrum odio ac sapien efficitur, at efficitur nisl dictum. Maecenas vitae arcu eget enim viverra eleifend. Mauris at dolor placerat, varius ante quis, consequat elit. Sed sodales congue bibendum. Morbi convallis eros vel nulla sagittis eleifend vel in lacus. Etiam imperdiet lorem eu turpis rutrum venenatis.</div>
    <div class="ads">
        <img src="http://demo.joomshaper.com/2012/neo/images/stories/demo/vertical-banner.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="comments">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So it's bad idea to use flexbox for this ?

Comment: That's for you to decide as it is down to the individual scenario, having said that Flexbox is relatively new and less supported than the solution I've provided.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would like Flex solution.

Comment: @MartynasŽilinskas Out of curiosity, can I ask why?

Comment: I was given task to make layout with flex. (For learning purpose) and I have been struggling for a while now.